# Unity 5x - UI Button - Awkward behavior

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So basically everything works. My button is round with image inserted as sprite for background. I also have text on my button. The awkward stuff is that the button works only if I pricesly aim over the text of the button which I moved on bottom right of the button.

Any idea why the graphic is not actually acting as button, but just the text of the button?

Comment: Oh! Something important. Actually in test mode it works fine. The problem occurs after the project was build and run. so i guess this makes it even more strange, because i test on same resolution and screen size so nothing is out of bounds or whatever.

Comment: Are there any active interactive object above or beneath the object?